# Modify admin configuration values on save

Tags: php, grav, pimple

I have created a configuration form in Grav's admin panel, and I want to extend/modify some of it's values on save.
More precisely, I have a list form element that looks like this in the blueprint:

```yaml
topics:
  type: list
  fields:
    .name:
      type: text
    .unique_id:
      type: text
      readonly: true
      default: generate_on_save
```

On save, I want to replace all `generate_on_save` values with a unique id.
I tried to hook into the [onAdminSave](https://learn.getgrav.org/16/admin-panel/extending/admin-events#onAdminSave) Event, but the Event Object contained just an instance of [\Grav\Common\Data\Blueprint](https://learn.getgrav.org/16/api#class-gravcommondatablueprint) and no actual form data. I then tried to modify the request object, but when I register the modified request in the grav container, I get an error `Cannot override frozen service 'request'`.

How can I accomplish this task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did the following which works fine:

- In config file */user/themes/quark/blueprints.yaml*, I copied your field definition.
- In Admin I added some topics on the config page of theme Quark.
- The 'Save' action was captured by the following eventhandler:

  ```
  public function onAdminSave(Event $event) {
    /** @var Data */
    $form = $event['object'];
    $topics = $form['topics'];

    foreach ($topics as &$topic) {
      if ($topic['unique_id'] === 'generate_on_save') {
        $topic['unique_id'] = str_rot13($topic['name']);
      }
    }

    // Note: Updated $form['topics'] must be re-assigned
    $form['topics'] = $topics;
  }
  ```
- The topics with there "unique" values have correctly been written to */user/config/themes/quark.yaml*

Comment: I didn't notice that the event in fact does contain the actual form data. Just one note, `foreach` works in this case if you pass the entry by reference - `foreach($topics as &$entry) { ... }`

Comment: @Benni, You're correct with respect to using reference. I've updated the answer.